# How to populate ActiveRecord's parent relation from custom query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have an ActiveRecord Schedule that has a parent Facility, like so:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :facility, class_name: 'Facility'
  ...
end
```

In my application I have a need to dynamically generate queries from the user input - and they can get rather complex. However, the bit I'm having trouble with should hopefully be straight forward from someone more familiar with the internals of rails.

I'm running a query where I left join the facility, like so:

```
   scope = scope.joins("LEFT JOIN facilities AS facility ON facility.id=schedules.facility_id")

   scope = scope.select('TO_JSON(facility.*) facility')
```

This makes the front-end code easier. There's a lot of existing architecture there that I won't get into for the purposes of this post - but we use a third party library that generates queries that we want to process on the backend, and it doesn't know how to pluralize the database names. We can (and do) transform the requests to account for this - but I'm trying to improve things by making the back-end a bit smarter if possible (we'll see if it's actually easier when all is said and done though).

The query executes as expected, and the resulting records have `facility` as an attribute (`model.has_attribute?("facility")` = `true`).

However, what does not work is that if I then call `model.facility` - rather than returning the facility that was just fetched it wants to instead go out and run a separate query to go fetch the parent facility instance...

So, what I'd like to know is: given that I use aliases like `facility` in place of `facilities` in my dynamic queries, how can I subsequently get my ActiveRecord model instances to use that data for its parent (or other) association(s)? I'd like to integrate it so that this happens behind the scenes, auto-magically as part of the query deserialization. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :)

```
def Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :facility, class_name: 'Facility'

  after_initialize do |model|
    # Deserialize the facility association retrieved via a dynamic query that uses 'facility' as an alias for the facilities table
    if has_attribute?(:facility)
      attrs = model.attributes.to_h
      model.facility = Facility.new(attrs['facility'])
    end
  end

  ...
end
```